# Android, How can I stop playing sound in html page?

Tags: android, audio

In my application I have web view. when i load my weblog in it, i can see my youtube movie. But when i leave that page or close application the sound of movie is still alive and is playing. how can i stop the sound in `onPause()` method?

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: In this case it is better to provide answer and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks Jin, last time I did this some persons nagged me why you did this its better to include it to your post, you can't ask question and answer it yourself. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27944/self-answer-vs-more-detail-in-the-question

Comment: Thanks Jin. Now, I have a nice evidence for my future answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had simple stupid answer that took near 5 hours of my time to find it.

Just add following line of code, the problem will be solved.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    wvObject.destroy();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call `destroy()` in `onPause()`. I think the better way is to call `wvObject.onPause()` in your activity `onPause()`, and to call `wvObject.onResume()`in your activity `onResume()`.